# Regular expression using struts not working

Tags: javascript, regex, struts

This is code for Email validation,here i have doubt is that regular expression correct or not..and one more explain each statement here what e.which represents here....like that i want to know each statement....

```
     function mailonly(e){
        var code;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
            var AllowRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (AllowRegex.test(character)) return true;
            return false;}
```

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to validate emailid

`ThisIsAnInvalidEmailId@invalid.com` would match with that regex but is that email id valid.**NO**

Your regex should be `^[^@]+@[^@]+$` and then to check if it's valid send a mail to that email address..If you receive any response email is valid!

Also emailid can contain characters like ^,$,!,~,-,(,) and many others..Even space is a valid character in email..

---

In case if you want to prevent users from making misspells you can use [mailcheck.js](https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck)

[image]